AugmentedImageUpdateListener is not working when Asynchronously creating bitmaps for AugmentedImageDatabase
I am trying to create an augmented image app using Sceneform, here in my activity what I am doing is, adding 20 images to the augmented images database by converting every image to a bitmap and then adding it to the augmented images database.
after a few moments when I start this activity, it says my app is not responding, wait or cancel,

app becoming unresponsive ("App Not Responding" or ANR) is likely caused by blocking operations being performed on the main thread. In Android, the main thread (also known as the UI thread) is responsible for handling user interactions and updating the UI. If it is blocked for more than a few seconds, the system will display an ANR dialog.

After knowing this, I adjusted my code to run Asynchronously for bitmap creation and adding it to the database, but then my problem was raised when I ran this code 'bitmap creation and adding it to database' , the listener for augmented image update arFragment.setOnAugmentedImageUpdateListener(this::onAugmentedImageTrackingUpdate); was not working since process runs Asynchronously, but when I run this code in the main thread synchronously, it runs correctly and the app starts unresponsive after few seconds, I don't understand why listener is not working properly when the process runs Asynchronously, this is the point I need some help to run my code Asynchronously and responsively..
here is my adjusted code
 @Override
public void onSessionConfiguration(Session session, Config config) {
    config.setLightEstimationMode(Config.LightEstimationMode.DISABLED);
    config.setPlaneFindingMode(Config.PlaneFindingMode.DISABLED);
    config.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
    config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
    

    database = new AugmentedImageDatabase(session);
    
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                for (OneModelAugmentedBooks bookData : augmentedBookDataWithUrisHelper.getAugmentedBooksDataList()) {
                    Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bookData.getBitmapUri());
                    String bitmapName = bookData.getModelAugmentedBooks().getBitmapName();

                    try (InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(bitmapUri)) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        database.addImage(bitmapName, bitmap);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        showToast("Unable to create bitmap - " + e.getMessage());
                        return;
                    }
                }
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    config.setAugmentedImageDatabase(database);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bitmap database loaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Check for image detection
    arFragment.setOnAugmentedImageUpdateListener(this::onAugmentedImageTrackingUpdate);
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                runOnUiThread(() -> showToast("Error loading bitmaps: " + e.getMessage()));
            }
        });
}

